# Managing a php multi language website with constants

Tags: php, multilingual

I would like to know what you think about the way I deal with the PHP multi-language feature for my website.

First, I recover a variable `$config['UserLang']` which contains the language. I recover it from the $_SESSION or from the database if the user is connected and has specified a language.

```
$config['UserLang'] = 'fr';
```

Then I open a file containing constants of the language:

```
require_once ('include/langs/'.$config['UserLang'].'.inc.php');
```

In the directory `include/langs` I have as many files as available languages, for example: `en.inc.php`, `fr.inc.php` and `es.inc.php`

And for example, the content of `en.inc.php` will be:

```
define("LANG_HOME_home", "Home");
define("LANG_HOME_contact", "Contact us");
define("LANG_HOME_phone", "Our phone");
define("LANG_HOME_address", "Our address");
define("LANG_HOME_desc", "Some description of the company <br> Another line about the company");
```

And then, when I display the DOM:

```
echo '
<div class="pad-t-20 txt-c">
    '.LANG_HOME_desc.'
</div>';
```

It's working fine bu is there anything I could to to improve it? Is there any other way which would be more conventional?

Thanks.

Comment: this (a small i18n-class) might by helpful: https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n

Comment: Yes, I have to take a look at this scipt

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use [Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) that is de facto standard for `i18n` and has strong support in PHP and PHP frameworks.

You can see tutorial [here](https://blog.udemy.com/php-gettext/) or [here](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html)